# How to fit on one page using mpdf?

Tags: php, mpdf

**Here is my code**

```
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$fname = date('Y-m-d-h-i-s') . "-" . ".pdf";
$mpdf->Output(__DIR__ . "/pdf/" . $fname);
```

But, It's 2 pages. I want to fit on one page.

Comment: Did you try without the AddPage() line ?

Comment: still same :(( @LBS

Comment: What does your $html variable contain ?

Comment: Only html tags are used. I used it `<div style = "page-break-after: always"> </div>`. I also reduced the font size. I couldn't find another solution. @LBS

Comment: By reducing the font size, I was able to fit it on my page. @LBS

Answer (score 1):

In this [basic example](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf-examples/blob/development/example001.php), no Addpage() is needed.

Comment: Still same. Or do I need to set the size? Height etc..